# Folders missing in SDK path selection window in intelliJ

Tags: dart, intellij-idea

I have newly installed IntelliJ IDE and installed the Dart plugging too. Now in the SDK path selection window I can't find many folders which is in fact there;( I can see these files and folders through terminal or file manager) further to add the confusion in the path selection window I could see some folders which are no existent.[image: folders showing in both shell and file manager][image: SDK path selection window - where many of the folders are missing]

Comment: Try to set the path sdk manually, by typing the path in the textbox

Comment: What IDE version do you use?

Comment: @y.bedrov IntelliJ Idea 2020.2.1 (Community Edition) That's my IDE Version.

Comment: @Mattia .   I tried that - manually setting the folder path, but it throws an error. Folder path selection has also an option to pick and drop a file, but that too fails

Answer (score 0):

Click 'Refresh' button in the Select Dart SDK Path dialog.